# Записать из базы в массив

Tags: массивы, база-данных, php, mysql

Сильно извиняюсь за тупой вопрос...

Есть запрос к БД:

```
TestsDb::query("SELECT iq,user_id,spent_time FROM table WHERE test_number='Test_2' GROUP BY user_id  ORDER BY  iq,spent_time DESC  ");

while ($Res = mysqli_fetch_array(TestsDb::$result)) {
    $id = $Res['user_id'];
    $iq = $Res['iq'];
}
```

Нужно записать это дело в массив вида: `"[index, $id, $iq]"`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ar = array();
while ($Res=mysqli_fetch_array(TestsDb::$result)){

   $ar[] = array(
      'id' => $Res['user_id'],
      'iq' => $Res['iq']
    );
}
```